# AngularJs ReferenceError: $locationProvider is not defined

Tags: angularjs

Estou com erro de

> ReferenceError: $locationProvider is not defined.

Estou usando angular-ui-router. Podem me ajudar?

obs: Removi o #.

```
    var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.router', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);

app.config([$locationProvider, function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $urlRouterProvider.when("", "/Index");

    $stateProvider
    .state('/Empresas', 
            { templateUrl: $("#linkBase").attr("href") + 'templates/Empresa/empresas.html', 
                 controller: 'EmpresaController' })
    .state('/Usuarios', 
            { templateUrl: $("#linkBase").attr("href") + 'templates/Usuario/usuarios.html', 
                controller: 'UsuarioController' })

}]);
```

Comment: Alterei o config e nao deu mais o erro porem as rotas nao funcionam. .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider)

Answer (score 0):

No AngularJS você precisa injetar as dependências na ordem que vai receber como parâmetro da função.

O **array** que a função ".config()" recebe como parâmetro deve estar assim:

1 - Lista de nomes em formato string com o nome registrado do objeto (provider, constants, etc) separados por vírgula.

2 - O último parâmetro do array **obrigatoriamente** deve ser uma função, que terá os items de dependência especificados previamente no array injetados nos parâmetros desta função, obedecendo a mesma ordem. Os nomes dos parâmetros na função podem ser definidos como melhor entender, porém é costume utilizar o mesmo nome que foi registrado.

Para corrigir seu erro, utilize abaixo:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.router', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider' 
   function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $urlRouterProvider.when("", "/Index");
    $stateProvider('/Empresas', 
        { templateUrl: $("#linkBase").attr("href") + 'templates/Empresa/empresas.html', 
             controller: 'EmpresaController' })
.state('/Usuarios', 
        { templateUrl: $("#linkBase").attr("href") + 'templates/Usuario/usuarios.html', 
            controller: 'UsuarioController' });
}]);
```